# How to pass item Id to event function WebForms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

For example, in asp.net mvc you can do this: `@Html.ActionLink("Action", "Controller", new{id="@item.Id"})`.

As a newbie, my question is how do I do the same, but in WebForms?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you going to have a post back.

The real queston is are you clicking on a button, dropdown list change, maybe a grid row click?

the context matters.

You going to take some action on the page. So, we might not actually have to pass anything at all, since with the web forms post-back model, then we in most cases don't have to pass some value, since you event model is based on cicking a button or whatever, and then a code stub behind runs for that action. So if you click on a button, and thus some code behind runs, that code stub has use of ALL controls on the current web page, so you don't need to pass anything at all.

So it comes down to context (when, where, what).

In the current example, you have item_id.

Ok, but where is that on the web page? Or is this from some grid view or whatever?

In web forms, you probably don't have to pass that value - you probably already have use of item_id.

But, in this context, what is item_id then?

are we to click a button, and then take action?

Jump to a new page?

Run some code behind on this page? So, again, context matters here.

In web forms, we not really interacting with the class, but are interacting wiht the web page - the separation of UI code and code behind kind of does not exist with web forms.
(this is also why those coming from desktop software find web forms so easy - it rather similar to desktop experience from a coding point of view)

In web forms? You would drop in that button, and then double click on the button, and you now have a code stub that runs behind. The only detail is where is item_id coming from?

You probably don't have to pass item_id, but probably can just use it in the code stubb.

So, you have:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Action", "Controller", new{id="@item.Id"}).

 Action = Link text
 "Controler" = method of action to run (worlds worst name Contoler!!!)
 new{id="@item.id") = contoller
```

Regardless, we want some text, and then a event/method (code) to run.

We have this:

```
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server"
            OnClick="LinkButton1_Click"
            CommandArgument="some optional value to pass"
            >Action Text</asp:LinkButton>
```

So, with a Linkbutton we don't call a controller, and pass a method.

We simple have a click event, and that code behind can walk the dog, do whatever you want.

So, with above, our code behind for clicking on that link button would be:

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  // link button click - do whatever we want

  LinkButton lBtn = sender;

  Debug.Print(lBtn.CommandArgument);
 }
```

So, we don't set/have/call some method of the controller, but get a whole new separate code stub that runs when we click on that link button.